# Append string if not already present

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have strings of time (how poetic) from a third party and some have the timezone while others don't. What I'd like to do append a timezone if one isn't present.

Here are examples of strings with timezones...

```
5:21 AM MT
10:01 PM MT
8:41 PM MT
```

But sometimes that `MT` is missing for whatever reason.

So, what I need to do is append `MT` after `AM` or `PM` if it's missing.

*(Note, I can't just check for `MT`. It could be any timezone. The primary goal here is to be able to append any timezone I choose after `AM` or `PM`).*

Comment: Can you just check if anything is present after AM/PM? Might there be other strings?

Comment: Yep, you could check that. Basically "if there is nothing after AM/PM, add timezone"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the AM/PM indicator is always there I would probably just check to see what the end of the string is and then append if necessary:

```
if string.match(/\ (A|P)M$/)
  string << " #{timezone}"
end
```

If not (ie: 24 time), you might be better off parsing the strings through a `Date` or `Time` parser and appending the timezone that way once the string is cast to the appropriate object.

Comment: The match-method could also be replaced with .end_with?('AM', 'PM')

Comment: @hirolau, I think your suggestion reads better.  Perhaps also insert `rstrip!` between `string` and `match`.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't like any of these so I decided to just [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-chomp) it off if it exists and then add it again. In your case:

`"#{time.chomp(' MT')} MT"`

Edit: this doesn't actually work for OPs edited use case (many different time zones) but *is* useful for both the original use case and potentially people finding this from Google (like me!).

Answer (score 2):

```
>> s = 'foobar'

>> s.ends_with?('bar') ? s : "#{s}bar"

=> "foobar"

>> s = 'foo'

>> s.ends_with?('bar') ? s : "#{s}bar"

=> "foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-regexp solution:

```
strings = ['5:21 AM MT', '8:41 PM MT',  '8:41 AM']
timezone = ' MT'
p strings.map{|time| time.end_with?('AM', 'PM') ? time+timezone : time}
#=> ["5:21 AM MT", "8:41 PM MT", "8:41 AM MT"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from my Perl days:

```
str = '5:21 AM MT'
str # => "5:21 AM MT"
str[/[AP]M$/] # => nil
str[/[AP]M$/] && str << ' MT'
str # => "5:21 AM MT"

str = '5:21 AM'
str # => "5:21 AM"
str[/[AP]M$/] # => "AM"
str[/[AP]M$/] && str << ' MT'
str # => "5:21 AM MT"
```

How's it work you ask? `str[/[AP]M$/] && str << ' MT'` is the magical thingie. Look at the result of the `str[/[AP]M$/]` lines:

- If the string doesn't end with either `"AM"` or `"PM"`, then `nil` is returned, which is false in Ruby, causing the `&&` condition to short-circuit.
- If the string ends with `"AM"` or `"PM"`, Ruby returns the matching string, as in the second example, which triggers the `&&` (and) and appends `' MT'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
time_string.sub(/([AP]M){1}$/, '\1 MT')
```

Answer (score -2):

So, if the string contains an `AM` or `PM` not followed by a space and a bunch of capital letters ending in `T`, append `MT` after the `AM` or `PM`?

```
timezone_string.sub(/( [AP]M)(?! [A-Z]+T)/,'\1 MT')
```

Comment: he said it could be any timezone, this is not valid as a check.

Comment: This regex doesn't check for `MT`.  Note that `EST`, `GMT`, `CEST` etc. all pass.  It does append `MT` if the timezone is absent, though.